# Displaying data from api array in node to a list in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, pug

I want to display data from the api to my pug page 
eg display car park names

Index.js below

```
var request     = require('request');
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var endpoints   = require("./endpoints")

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res){ 
request.get('http://data.corkcity.ie/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc', 
function(error, response, body){
    var carPark = JSON.parse(body);
    var carParkAll = carPark.result.records;
res.render('home', { parking: body});
   });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('3000');
})
```

home.pug

```
doctype html
html
    body
        p #{parking}
```

endpoints.js

```
(function (){
'use strict';

module.exports = {
   parking:  "http://localhost:3000/",
   };
}());
```

Which displays 
 [all of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8PBU.png)

Basically i want to show a list of all the car parks.
I am only learning this so i am still very much new.
Would love any form of feedback, cheers!

Comment: do you have a specific question or problem you wanted to ask?

Comment: how would i get a list of the carparks from the api to show in the pug page?

since the results are in an array im not to sure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to iterate over the items using one of pug's iteration options: https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Something like this:

```
ul
  each park in parking
    li= park
```

The same can be applied to more complex objects:

```
  each park in parking
    div.park_item
       p park.name
       p park.spaces
       p park.price
```

The `each` keyword is pug's way of iterating over an array, where `park` will hold the object during each loop. Therefore you can access the object's properties inside the `each` loop using `park.name`, etc.

Comment: Ok yeah i tryed the first on and it is displaying a list but the list is empty

`each records in parking
            li= identifer
`

Thanks for the reply im on the right track

Comment: What's `identifier`? The object inside the `each` loop should be `records` in this case, so you will need to reference that, like so: `li= records.title`

Comment: ok in index.js i changed `res.render('home', { parking: body});` to   `res.render('home', { parking: carParkAll});
    });`
and also changed back to `each park in parking
            li= park`
and now i have a list of 8 [object Object]

Comment: then i changed `each park in parking li= park.name` and got the list of car parks
Thank you, i understand now :) cheers!!

Comment: Ah! Right, I thought that's what you were doing to begin with. Didn't realize you were sending the whole body. Glad you got it to work.